# Proguard not keeping GSON's JsonScope fields and methods

Tags: android, gson, proguard, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit and when building a release, I'm seeing the following:

```
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced method 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope[] values()' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope EMPTY_DOCUMENT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced method 'int ordinal()' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope EMPTY_ARRAY' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope NONEMPTY_ARRAY' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope EMPTY_OBJECT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope DANGLING_NAME' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope NONEMPTY_OBJECT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope NONEMPTY_DOCUMENT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader$2: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope CLOSED' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced method 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope[] values()' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope NONEMPTY_DOCUMENT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced method 'int ordinal()' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope EMPTY_DOCUMENT' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope EMPTY_ARRAY' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope NONEMPTY_ARRAY' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter$1: can't find referenced field 'com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope DANGLING_NAME' in program class com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope
Warning:there were 17 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
```

My proguard-project.txt is as follows:

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn android.test.**

-keepattributes Signature

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.otto.Subscribe public *;
    @com.squareup.otto.Produce public *;
}

-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }

-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Package path for GSON models
-keep class com.threadflip.android.api.** { *; }
-keep interface com.threadflip.android.api.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

So, it seems like proguard should keep `com.google.gson.stream.JsonScope` but apparently that's not happening, and I have no idea why.

Any help appreciated!